# Como evitar de hacer un registro duplicado en trigger mysql

Tags: mysql, trigger

Esto intentando de hacer un trigger de insert pero antes de eso coloco una condición para validar un campo en especifico si ya está en tabla para que no le inserte y no me duplique el registro.

actualmente he intentado esto pero en todos me sale error:

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `adtw`$$

DROP TRIGGER /*!50032 IF EXISTS */ `profes_adic`$$

CREATE
    /*!50017 DEFINER = 'root'@'%' */
    TRIGGER `profes_adic` AFTER INSERT ON `profesionales` 
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    
    DECLARE @nit(SELECT nit FROM facw.nits)
    
    IF (@nit <> NEW.identidad) THEN BEGIN
    
     INSERT INTO facw.nits (
            tipoid, nit, nombre, direccion, barrio, telefonos, email1, usuariocre, usuariomod, fechacre)
         VALUES (
            NEW.tipoid, NEW.identidad, NEW.nombre=CONCAT(NEW.nombre, " ", NEW.apellidos), NEW.direccion,
            NEW.barrio, NEW.telefonos, NEW.email, NEW.usuariocre, NEW.usuariomod, NEW.fechacre
         );
       
    END; END IF;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

> Error Code: 1064
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '@nit(SELECT nit FROM facw.nits)

---

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `adtw`$$

DROP TRIGGER /*!50032 IF EXISTS */ `profes_adic`$$

CREATE
    /*!50017 DEFINER = 'root'@'%' */
    TRIGGER `profes_adic` AFTER INSERT ON `profesionales` 
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    
    IF NEW.identidad != nits.nit THEN BEGIN
    
     INSERT INTO facw.nits (
            tipoid, nit, nombre, direccion, barrio, telefonos, email1, usuariocre, usuariomod, fechacre)
         VALUES (
            NEW.tipoid, NEW.identidad, NEW.nombre=CONCAT(NEW.nombre, " ", NEW.apellidos), NEW.direccion,
            NEW.barrio, NEW.telefonos, NEW.email, NEW.usuariocre, NEW.usuariomod, NEW.fechacre
         );
       
    END; END IF;
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

> Error Code: 1064
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 15

---

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `adtw`$$

DROP TRIGGER /*!50032 IF EXISTS */ `profes_adic`$$

CREATE
    /*!50017 DEFINER = 'root'@'%' */
    TRIGGER `profes_adic` AFTER INSERT ON `profesionales` 
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    
    
    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM facw.`nits` 
          WHERE nit = NEW.identidad)
          
          THEN BEGIN
       
     INSERT INTO facw.nits (
            tipoid, nit, nombre, direccion, barrio, telefonos, email1, usuariocre, usuariomod, fechacre)
         VALUES (
            NEW.tipoid, NEW.identidad, NEW.nombre=CONCAT(NEW.nombre, " ", NEW.apellidos), NEW.direccion,
            NEW.barrio, NEW.telefonos, NEW.email, NEW.usuariocre, NEW.usuariomod, NEW.fechacre
         );
       
    END; END IF;
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

> Error Code: 1064
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 19

Comment: Qué error sale? Edita la pregunta y añádelo, por favor

Comment: @Alfabravo Listo compañero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay varias cosas:

- Para este caso no necesitas `DECLARE`. Si quieres profundizar sobre esto consulta las respuesta a [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3075147/5587982).
- Aparte del error de sintaxis al obtener la variable, me parece que la lógica que implementas no es correcta. Si he entendido bien, se trata de evitar la inserción si en la tabla `nits` existe una columna `nit` que tenga el mismo valor que la nueva columna `identidad` que se estaría queriendo insertar. Si es así, entonces lo más óptimo sería contar la cantidad de registros que cumplen ese criterio, guardarnos en la variable (la he llamado `@myNit` para evitar confusiones) y posteriormente verificar si la variable es igual a cero, lo cual significará que no hay registros con ese criterio.
- Aquí tienes un error, aunque de lógica: `NEW.nombre=CONCAT(NEW.nombre, " ", NEW.apellidos)`, supongo que lo que quieres es concatenar `nombre` y `apellidos`, en cuyo caso habría que ponerlo así: `CONCAT(NEW.nombre, " ", NEW.apellidos)`
- Finalmente, nunca mejor dicho, te está faltando el `END` del bloque `FOR EACH ROW BEGIN`. Escribe tu código indentado siempre, así verás los errores y compararás con facilidad cada bloque.

Aplicando lo dicho, así debería funcionar:

```
DELIMITER $$

    USE `adtw`$$

    DROP TRIGGER /*!50032 IF EXISTS */ `profes_adic`$$

    CREATE
    /*!50017 DEFINER = 'root'@'%' */
    TRIGGER `profes_adic` AFTER INSERT ON `profesionales`
 
        FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
            SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @myNit 
            FROM facw.nits WHERE facw.nits.nit=NEW.identidad;
            IF (@myNit = 0) THEN 
                BEGIN
                    INSERT INTO facw.nits (
                            tipoid, 
                            nit, 
                            nombre, 
                            direccion,  
                            barrio, 
                            telefonos, 
                            email1, 
                            usuariocre, 
                            usuariomod, 
                            fechacre
                        )
                        VALUES 
                        (
                           NEW.tipoid, 
                           NEW.identidad,
                           CONCAT(NEW.nombre, " ", NEW.apellidos), 
                           NEW.direccion, 
                           NEW.barrio, 
                           NEW.telefonos, 
                           NEW.email, 
                           NEW.usuariocre, 
                           NEW.usuariomod, 
                           NEW.fechacre
                        );           
                END;
            END IF;
        END; $$ DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Hola amigo, mira que modifique facw.nit=NEW.identidad; por facw.nits.nit porque no reconocía la columna pero el detalle es que no me esta funcionando la inserción.

Comment: @Juanzu ¿te refieres a la parte del `WHERE` donde se hace el `COUNT(*)`? ¿Cuándo dices que no te está funcionando a qué te refieres exactamente?  ¿Da alǵun error? ¿Qué error? Aclara un poco también si tengo razón en mi intuición, pues eso del `COUNT(*)` basado en el WHERE lo deduje analizando tu código, pero no expones claramente en la pregunta ni en el código que intentabas implementar que el INSERT debe hacerse segú ese criterio.

Comment: Por cierto, yo comentí un error en esa consulta, debería ser así: **`SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @myNit FROM facw.nits WHERE facw.nits.nit=NEW.identidad;`** Pero considera que en esa instrucción `facw` hace referencia a la base de datos. Ahí estás diciendo que la tabla `nits` se encuentra en una base de datos llamada `facw` ¿Es así en tu contexto o no? Sea como sea, dime el error que te está dando el código.

Comment: Ya no me sale el error porque hice el cambio que mencionas anteriormente. Pero no me funciona la inserción porque hago un registro en tabla profesionales y cuando reviso la tabla nits no está dicho registros. Lo que quiero decir es que no me sale error en el trigger pero no me esta funcionando.

Comment: @Juanzu Entiendo. ¿Podrías explicar la lógica que hay que seguir? Como te decía en un anterior comentario, deduje que la inserción debía ocurrir cuando en la columna `nit` de la tabla `nits` no haya ningún registro con un valor igual a `NEW.identidad` ...

Comment: Tal cual como lo deduces así es.

Comment: @Juanzu, entonces cuando la inserción no ocurre es porque la condición no se cumple. En ese caso, comprueba los datos e intenta insertar un registro que pase el filtro que hay en el `IF` del TRIGGER. O sea, prueba a insertar una `identidad` que no exista en `nit`.

Comment: Ya me funciono, se te agradece tu colaboración